# is $.index() equivalent of nth-child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, indexing, css-selectors

is the return value of

```
$(element).index();
```

compatible with CSS `nth-child(index)` ?

I did some tests and it seems it is. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no... `index()` is `0` based index, where as `nth-child` used `1` based index

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3UnTD/)

Comment: actually, if he answered the question, you should select it as the answer.